# Using a label within a bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap nav:

[image]

The highlighted bit is currently a list element of the nav and as such, the color changes on hover over and it is meant to be used as a navigation action.  I would like to instead use it as a static label, meant to show the user something about where they are in the application.  I know that I can added the class 'disabled' to make it look 'less' clickable, but it still changes slightly on hover over, and displays a cursor other than the default.

I'm hoping to have it display as a simple centered label that doesn't appear to be clickable in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pointer-events: none;` on the label will disable the element from registering any mouse events, including hover effects and bypassing the issue you had with it.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this question I decided to just override Bootstrap's styles for the particular element in question so that they appear statically.

html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></a></li>
  <li class="label-li disabled"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.label-li {
  width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.label-li a {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

the two lines ended by `!important` are what prevent's bootstrap's style from taking over.

Comment: You could also use `pointer-events: none;` so the element doesn't even register any hover effects.

Comment: That solution is even more elegant that what I came up with.  Feel free to answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0):

While your solution does work, I would recommend instead looking at the :hover selector (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp). This is what bootstrap does internally to create the various effects, and with it you can override all of the properties it assigns, such as the color and cursor change. Just assign them to the same values as normal using :hover and nothing will change, no need to use the !important.

Comment: I played around with the hover selector a bit and was unable to get it to do what I wanted.  The chrome Developer tools (from what I can tell) doesn't do a very good job of showing you the css styles for those different states. Kevin's solution seems like the easiest way to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm glad that you at least tried that before going with !important. And I agree, Kevin's solution is better, I was unaware of pointer-events.